# Tests are running twice when upgraded from cucumber 4 to cucumber 6

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

My project have 2 runners files and and 3 feature files and I was using cucumber 4. My team wants to upgrade to cucumber 6 and I am running through terminal using below command
mvn test -DEnv=qa -Dcucumber.options="classpath:sec/test/java/runner/" -Dcucumber.filter.tags="Run123"
Here i am trying run feature with mentioned tag.
But I could the same feature is running twice. Can anyone help me on this

I tried running it from run configuration but nothing worked

Comment: You've gotta read the changes before you upgrade https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm#upgrading

Comment: Your question is probably also not complete, Cucumber tags include the `@` so you should use `-Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Run123"`. But I suspect you tried to redact the actual tag name. Please make sure that your question describes your problem accurately https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask